# SQLite/C#: Design a entity which is a child of many parent entities

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-relationship

I have these relations:

```
1 Period has N Documents
1 Pupil has N Documents
1 Report has N Documents
```

These are my C# entities:

```
class Period
{
   public int PeriodId {get;set;}   
   public List<Document> Documents {get;private set;}
}

class Pupil
{
   public int PupilId {get;set;}   
   public List<Document> Documents {get;private set;}
}

class Period
{
   public int ReportId {get;set;}  
   public List<Document> Documents {get;private set;} 

}

class Document
{
   public int DocumentId {get;set;}

   // ??? 
   public int PeriodId {get;set;}
   public int PupilId {get;set;}
   public int ReportId {get;set;} 

   // ??? OR just a general Foreign-Key Id like
   public int Id_FK {get;set;}
}
```

The problem is this:

When I have a Document with the PeriodId 33 there are chances that I could also have a PupilId 33 because both tables use primary key/autoincrement. So there could be a pupil AND a period having the Id 33. Doing now an INNER JOIN on both tables I would return 2 documents from my sqlite query although I should get ONLY **ONE**.

How would you solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create three [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) (say, period_docuemnts, pupil_documents, and report_documents). This may be a bit more general than necessary (a single document could belong to multiple periods with that, also), but its more normal.

Comment: Well Martin actually a single document can only belong to a one period. It is not possible to add the same document id to another entity. I would even say thats not need because a period has a unique content. I do not think that I need to be able to add the same "math sheet" twice because I do not teach the same lesson twince a year. That would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your ERD for SQLite, and after that is correct, then you can do the object-relational mapping in C#. You have four main entities, each requiring a table in SQLite: Document, Pupil, Period, Report.  And then you need a way to express the fact that each entity (row) in each of those three tables can be associated with one or more documents. As Martin said, that is done using a "junction" aka linking table.

Now, in C#, if you want to have a denormalized object called Document, you can do this:

```
class Document
{
   public int DocumentId {get;set;}

   // ??? 
   public int PeriodId {get;set;}
   public int PupilId {get;set;}
   public int ReportId {get;set;} 

   // ??? OR just a general Foreign-Key Id like
  public int Id_FK {get;set;}
}
```

only if a document can be associated with one, and only one Period, one and only one Pupil, and one and only one Report. If a document can be linked to more than one of those entities, these properties of your Document class would have to allow for multiple values, i.e. they would have to be arrays or lists.

Comment: thats the scenario: the user can add document "excel sheet" with DocId 33 ONLY to ONE entity. If he adds the same document "excel sheet" to another entity its another DocId like 34.